# FFT on my oscilloscope is not detecting a peak which is a peak

Tags: pwm, oscilloscope, fft

I am having a strange problem and it's due to that lack of my info about signals.

I examined a **PWM** output from my MCU under *sds1104x-e* oscilloscope which is **656KHZ** with a duty cycle of around **45.5%** and converted the signal into FFT domain to examine the harmonics, RMS, and so on.

Anyway look at the first image, it represents Vrms versus frequency in the case of using DC coupling, as you can see there is a peak frequency at **15.25KHZ** whose amplitude is higher than the amplitude at 656KHZ but still not detected as a peak point.

[image]

when I changed the coupling to AC, that first peak disappeared but the amplitude of the other 2 peaks increased.

[image]

I don't know why this happened, but hear me out. I am just trying to understand how to convert a PWM signal to an analog signal using a low pass filter and one of the things the tutorial looks at is the FFT of the signal, my problem is I concluded that the analog equivalent value of the PWM signal should be equal to the summation of Vrms of the composing signals, so my PWM signal shall produce a **1.5v** analog signal, in first image the summation of the 2 Vrms of the signals is actually around **1.49v** while in the second image, it's around **1.7v**, so a lot of question and I really don't understand what's going on.

Comment: *is* that at 15 kHz, or is that the DC peak of a signal with DC offset? I wouldn't be surprised if a spectrum analyzer ignored the DC peak when you use the peak-detect function.

Comment: @Hearth, I really don't know, it just shows a signal at 15KHZ with a high peak but not detected, when I re-run the oscilloscope again, it changes from 15KHZ to 2KHZ, so I guess it may be DC offset, I really don't know but what I know is the frequency of my PWM signal is 656KHZ, I don't know where that low frequency signal came from.

Comment: I assume the "15 kHz" at this frequency resolution is the first slot of the spectrum and represents the DC part of the signal.